# Make arrays of different shape and dimension equal in shape and dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 different shape and dimension arrays and want to update both of them in order to have a consistent shape and dimension by filling 1 in the places.

I am able to do this by using loops, **I am looking for an answer without loops.**

```
A = np.arange(4).reshape(-1,1)
B = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)

A.shape  => (4, 1)
B.shape  => (3, 3, 3)

# Now A.shape should be (4, 3, 3) and B.shape should be (4, 3, 3)
```

Now I need help to write a function that takes in 2 arrays and return 2 arrays of the same dimension and shape by filling 1's in the places.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show how you do this with loops.  If you know how to make an array of `ones` with the right size, and you know the basics of assigning values to a slice/block of an array, the no-loop version should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more refined way but one possible solution would be:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.arange(4).reshape(-1, 1)

In [3]: B = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)

In [4]: def resize_to_bigger(A: np.ndarray, B: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
   ...:     taller, smaller = (A, B) if A.size >= B.size else (B, A)
   ...:     # if both sizes are equal reshape to first passed array
   ...:     if taller.size == smaller.size:
   ...:         return smaller.copy().reshape(taller)
   ...:     else:
   ...:         C = np.ones(taller.size)
   ...:         C[:smaller.size] = smaller.flatten()
   ...:         return C.reshape(taller.shape)
   ...:

In [5]: resize_to_bigger(A, B)
Out[5]:
array([[[0., 1., 2.],
        [3., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

Note, that there's no checking for `dtype`s at all.